# Spring Tool Suite with SVN integration - what does the number in parens next to java class mean

Tags: java, svn, spring-tool-suite, subclipse

I recently started seeing a number in parentheses appear next to my java classes in Spring Tool Suite. The project is configured to connect to SVN. What does the number mean? I see it even after committing changes or updating to the latest revision of a file. See the highlighted number (1) in parens in the image below:

[image]

Here is the Label Decorations tab:
[image]

Comment: which SVN integration do you use? Depending on that I would add another tag to get people familiar with that integration on board for this question.

Comment: The 'decoration' after the file name there looks like it is Subclipse rather than Subversive as the SVN integration?  You can see the format for those decorations in Window/Preferences.  Navigate to Team/SVN/Label Decorations, and then the Text tab.  It looks like it might have been customised there though?  The default format is `{added_flag}{dirty_flag}{name} {revision}  {date}  {author}` - with nothing after the author.

Comment: Thank you - I double checked the setting and the format is the default as you mentioned. Mystery remains unsolved.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Show History on the file?  My only thought would be the author name has the (1) in it.  Otherwise, it could be some other plugin is adding this decoration.  Any plugin could potentially add decorators to the files in the list.